# Yii2 migrating with multiple databases

Tags: database, yii2, connection, yii2-advanced-app, migrate

I am creating databases from my form.
At the end of the creation I want to run the migrates that I have inside the migrations folder.

I tried using several methods, shell_exec, ConsoleCommandRunner and MigrateController. But no method has worked for me.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Why don't the commands run?
It only starts the migrate in the created database.

[image]

[image]